# Receive autoreply messages in Google Group

Tags: google-groups

I have a large Google Group. When I send email to the group members, all members receive the email. The question is how to receive their auto reply messages if they have it enabled?. I haven't receive a single auto reply message from any of the members, but when I send normal email to them from my work email address, I receive their auto reply message. Can anybody can tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: What's your group Reply-To address set to ? ('Post replies' in Settings/Email options)